# Use of folders in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Is it possible to use folders within our WordPress site for the content organization?  Any issue in doing this?

We would like to use the folders to group related pages & content, so that we can set up tools (live chat, website forms, etc...) to route inquires to the appropriate groups based on which folder the inquiry was generated from, or being able to analyze the data in google analytics by folder.

I've been told this is not possible or creates problems with themes and other site management tools within WordPress, which doesn't seem correct to me.

Currently, all pages are located after the root domain such as acme.com/....

Ideally, we would like to organize our site like the example below.

```
acme.com/products/...
acme.com/services/...
acme.com/jobs/...
acme.com/about us/...
acme.com/blog/...
```

Comment: I beleive your question should be asked here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Great.  Thanks for the help!